# How to update 2 different rows depending on the WHERE and AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a table, and depending on the where and AND depends of the row I want to update, so if `message_to` and `message_id` match update `message_deleted_to` OR if `message_user`, `message_id` matches them update the `messaged_deleted_from`

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message_body` text NOT NULL,
  `message_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_from_read` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `message_to_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message_deleted_from` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_deleted_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_permdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_type` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `messages`
--

INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_id`, `message_user`, `message_subject`, `message_body`, `message_to`, `message_from_read`, `message_to_read`, `message_date`, `message_deleted_from`, `message_deleted_to`, `message_permdeleted`, `message_type`, `message_deleted`) VALUES
(6, 12, 'lol', 'lol', 1, 1, 0, '2015-12-14 04:54:32', 0, 0, 0, 'sent', 0),
```

What I want to accomplish (I know this code won't work, I'm just trying to show you what I want to do)

```
UPDATE messages 
    SET message_deleted_from = 1 
    WHERE message_user = ? 
    AND message_id = ?

    OR SET messages_delete_to = 1
    WHERE message_to
    AND message_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE messages 
    SET message_deleted_from =  
    CASE WHEN message_user = ? 
    AND message_id = ? THEN 1 ELSE message_deleted_from END,

    messages_delete_to = 
    CASE WHEN message_to=? 
    AND message_id = ? THEN 1 ELSE messages_delete_to END
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET messages_delete_to = 
       CASE 
        WHEN message_to = '3' 
       ' at line 11 in

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't too far off.

```
UPDATE messages
SET message_deleted_from = 1
WHERE (message_user = ? AND message_id = ?) 

UPDATE messages
SET message_deleted_to = 1
WHERE (message_to = ? AND message_id = ?)
```

Comment: Your query is not correct: ( if message_to and message_id match update message_deleted_to OR if message_user, message_id matches them update the messaged_deleted_from)